# asp.net core 'No route matches the supplied values' with controller-level route values

Tags: asp.net-core

The following controller throws a `System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values` exception when posting a new item (by the `CreatedAtRoute` method):

```cs
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/offices/{officeId}/[controller]")]
    public class ResourcesController : ControllerBase
    {
        /* ... */
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(Guid officeId) =>
            this.Ok(await this.client.GetResourcesAsync(officeId));

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetResourceById")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(Guid officeId, string id)
        {
            var resource = await this.client.GetResourceAsync(officeId, id);
            return resource == null ? (IActionResult) this.NotFound() : this.Ok(resource);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(Guid officeId, Resource resource)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await this.client.CreateResourceAsync(officeId, resource);
                return this.CreatedAtRoute("GetResourceById", new {officeId, id = resource.Id}, result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(e, "Error while creating a resource");
                return this.StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or is there another way to use route values specified at controller level?

Tested on **asp.net core 3 (preview 8)**.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, can you include the URL you're attempting to post with.

Comment: What is the url that you're posting data on?

Comment: You can try with `[FromRoute]` & `[FromBody]` like `public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromRoute]Guid officeId, [FromBody]Resource resource)`

Comment: _“[…] when posting a new item”_ – So you only get the error when trying to reach your `PostAsync` action? The other actions do work?

Comment: The post action works, but the exception is thrown by the `CreatedAtRoute` method

Comment: @fra Could you please show us the definition of `Resource` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id value of the resource was `null`, and therefore the anonymous object passed to the method was missing the **id** value, which is not optional on the route template and therefore the route was not found.

Using `result.Id` solved it, because the client was assigning the id (generated by the MongoDb instance behind).

Answer (score -1):

I think its because of the parameters that you gave.

In this line you are giving 2 anonymus objects params to your root, but your root contains and asks for 1 parameter.

```
return this.CreatedAtRoute("GetResourceById", new {officeId, id = resource.Id}, result);
```

**EDIT**

I think the {id} parameter makes a conflict over your root parameters.

```
[Route("api/offices/{officeId}/[controller]")]
```

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetResourceById")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(Guid officeId, string id)
        {
            var resource = await this.client.GetResourceAsync(officeId, id);
            return resource == null ? (IActionResult) this.NotFound() : this.Ok(resource);
        }
```